# MSSQL Script to export entire database

Tags: sql-server

It's possible create a script (to launch from a stored procedure) that export the entire database (schema + data) into a .sql file?

I need this to make a backup from a MSSQL 2019 and I need to restore to MSSQL 2017... Using `Tasks->Generate Scripts` from SSMS it's possible do what I need, but I wish schedule this and the best way I think is made a script to launch from a stored procedure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you can take a look on SSIS-task "transfer database" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/transfer-database-task?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Create a stored procedure to backup using command  `BACKUP DATABASE  { database_name | @database_name_var } 
TO DISK ...` and restore using command  `RESTORE DATABASE { database_name | @database_name_var }
 [ FROM <backup_device> [ ,...n ] ] `.  Does it work?

Comment: @AnanthMK it works, but not with restoring to previous MSSQL versions...

Comment: The short answer is no. SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) might be of some use here - and perhaps put your schema into a source-control system as well. TBH it doesn't make much sense to me to schedule over-writing of a schema in this manner - so I smell a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the script that will allow you to backup each database within your instance of SQL Server

```
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(256) -- database name  
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(512) -- path for backup files  
DECLARE @fileName NVARCHAR(512) -- filename for backup  
DECLARE @fileDate NVARCHAR(40) -- used for file name
 
-- specify database backup directory
SET @path = 'C:\test\'  
 
-- specify filename format
SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112) 
 
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR  
SELECT name 
FROM master.sys.databases 
WHERE name = @name 
AND state = 0 -- database is online
AND is_in_standby = 0 -- database is not read only for log shipping
 
OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   
 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
   SET @fileName = @path + @name + '_' + @fileDate + '.sql'  
   BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName  
 
   FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   
END   
 
CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

You have to change the @path to the appropriate backup directory.

NOTE: Make sure that you have read and write access to the DB

Comment: thanks for this useful script, but this make a binary backup, and if I try to restore into a previous MSSQL version, doesn't work